# Mapping from multiindex to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, multi-index

I have a huge multiindex dataframe. I whish to create new columns based on the part of the content of the multiindex. This is what I have:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo','foo','qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'eight','one', 'two'],
          ['green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'green','blue', 'black']  ]
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index=arrays)
s.index.names = ['p1','p2','p3']

s
                         0
p1  p2    p3              
bar one   green  -0.676472
    two   green  -0.030377
    three blue   -0.957517
baz one   blue    0.710764
    four  black   0.404377
foo one   black  -0.286358
    two   orange -1.620832
    eight green   0.316170
qux one   blue   -0.433310
    two   black   1.127754
```

This is what I want:

```
                         0  x1  x2  x3
p1  p2    p3                          
bar one   green   1.563381   1   0   1
    two   green   0.193622   0   0   0
    three blue    0.046728   1   0   0
baz one   blue    0.098216   0   0   0
          black   1.826574   0   1   0
foo one   black  -0.120856   1   1   1
    two   orange  0.605020   0   0   0
    eight green   0.693606   0   0   0
qux one   blue    0.588244   1   1   1
    two   black  -0.872104   1   1   1
```

Now, in pseudo code I want to:

```
if (p1 =='bar') & (p2 == 'one') & (p3 == 'green'): s['x1'] = 1, s['x3'] = 1
if (p1 == 'bar') & (p3 == 'blue'): s['x1'] = 1
if (p1 == 'baz') & (p3 == 'black'): s['x2'] = 1
if (p1 =='foo') & (p2 == 'one') & (p3 == 'black'): s['x1'] = 1, s['x2'] = 1, s['x3'] = 1
if (p1 == 'qux'): s['x1'] = 1, s['x2'] = 1, s['x3'] = 1
```

I.e. based on the values of the columns of the multiindex, I want to assign 1 to the new x-columns. 
I am looking for a vectorized approach like numpy.select (condition, choice), but I can't get numpy.select to work with more than one choice per condition.

Since I have 14 index columns I would prefer if the name of the column I condition on is used explicitly (i.e. `(p1 == 'bar') & (p2 == 'one')` is preferred instead of `['bar','one',]`).

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible use selection by [index slices](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) and set columns by `1` like:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
s = s.assign(x1=0, x2=0, x3=0)
s.loc[idx['bar','one','green'], ['x1','x3']] = 1
s.loc[idx['bar',:,'blue'], ['x1']] = 1 
s.loc[idx['baz',:,'black'], ['x2']] = 1 
s.loc[idx['foo','one','black'], ['x1','x2','x3']] = 1
s.loc[idx['qux',:,:],  ['x1','x2','x3']] = 1

print (s)
                         0  x1  x2  x3
p1  p2    p3                          
bar one   green   0.152556   1   0   1
    two   green   0.488762   0   0   0
    three blue    0.037346   1   0   0
baz one   blue    1.903518   0   0   0
    four  black   0.589922   0   1   0
foo one   black   0.871984   1   1   1
    two   orange  0.514062   0   0   0
    eight green  -0.177246   0   0   0
qux one   blue    0.740046   1   1   1
    two   black   0.755664   1   1   1
```

EDIT:

```
def get_i(lev, val):
    return s.index.get_level_values(lev) == val

s = s.assign(x1=0, x2=0, x3=0)
s.loc[get_i('p1','bar') & get_i('p2','one') & get_i('p3','green'), ['x1','x3']] = 1
s.loc[get_i('p1','bar') & get_i('p3','blue'), ['x1']] = 1 
s.loc[get_i('p1','baz') & get_i('p3','black'), ['x2']] = 1 
s.loc[get_i('p1','foo') & get_i('p2','one') & get_i('p3','black'), ['x1','x2','x3']] = 1
s.loc[get_i('p1','qux'), ['x1','x2','x3']] = 1


print (s)
                         0  x1  x2  x3
p1  p2    p3                          
bar one   green  -0.029773   1   0   1
    two   green  -1.505461   0   0   0
    three blue    1.819085   1   0   0
baz one   blue    0.645498   0   0   0
    four  black  -1.119554   0   1   0
foo one   black   1.002072   1   1   1
    two   orange -0.461030   0   0   0
    eight green  -2.565080   0   0   0
qux one   blue    0.286967   1   1   1
    two   black  -0.522340   1   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpfull. I have 14 index columns (p1 to p14). I would like to explicitly include the name (i.e. p1, p2,) of the column in question in the solution (i.e. p1 =='bar' instead of just ['bar']). It minimizes the risk of mistakes. Can that be done?

Comment: @Hartvigsen - Answer was edited, unfortunately need compare levels of `MultiIndex`, not possible set by level name.

Answer (score 1):

An extension to @jezrael's solution : combination of [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) and [index slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas.IndexSlice) could help with usage of the index names :

```
#conditions
cond1 = s.query('p1=="bar" and p2=="one" and p3=="green"').index
cond2 = s.query('p1=="bar" and p3=="blue"').index
cond3 = s.query('p1=="baz" and p3=="black"').index
cond4 = s.query('p1=="foo" and p2=="one" and p3=="black"').index
cond5 = s.query('p1=="qux"').index

idx = pd.IndexSlice

#create zero columns
s = s.assign(x1=0,x2=0,x3=0)

#assign values : 
s.loc[idx[cond1], ["x1","x3"]] = 1
s.loc[idx[cond2], ["x1"]] = 1
s.loc[idx[cond3], ['x2']] = 1
s.loc[idx[cond4], ['x1', 'x2','x3']] = 1
s.loc[idx[cond5], ['x1', 'x2','x3']] = 1

                     0      x1  x2  x3
p1  p2  p3              
bar one green   1.122544    1   0   1
    two green   0.157234    0   0   0
  three blue    0.760863    1   0   0
baz one blue    -0.194400   0   0   0
   four black   0.937159    0   1   0
foo one black   -0.986325   1   1   1
    two orange  -0.002486   0   0   0
  eight green   0.067649    0   0   0
qux one blue    1.024345    1   1   1
    two black   0.884644    1   1   1
```